# How can I change or override android/ios back button's action in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to make a change in my page (changing a bool in setState etc...) when the user presses the back button.

I looked it up and I know people use WillPopScope to override the default "back" action, but in all of the examples they were just popping the page, and I need to do a custom function instead of that, and have no Idea how to do so.
my function looks like this, and I need to run in when the user pressed the back button:

```
Future<void> backToCats() async{
    setState(() {
      isLoaded=false;
    });
    if(isFromSearch){
      loadCategories();
    }
    setState(() {
      showingBrands=false;
      isLoaded=true;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform custom logic in the onWillPop argument of a WillPopScope widget. Just make sure to return true or false at the end to indicate whether the page is allowed to pop. WillPopScope will activate for the back button, and other actions that automatically navigate back such as swiping from the side of the screen on iOS.

For example, if you need to set a bool to false in your stateful widget, it would look something like this

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    setState(() => myBool = false);
    return true;
  }
  child: ...
);
```

Comment: it does not work, even when I just print something in onWillPop.  I'm using a BottomNavigationBar, maybe it has something to do with that?